# Multipart/form-data upload - Nodejs - expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Since express.multipart is removed from the Express 4.x library, what will be the best way to handle file upload in expressjs?

Comment: Alternatives are listed in Connect's documentation: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yea but these libraries looks not as clean as the old one, which one do u prefer?

Comment: Technically many of those came from the old one. connect-multiparty is more or less that one you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23063317/971592) about multipart. I would recommend multiparty:

Have you given [node-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) a try? Here's example usage from the README:

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty')
  , http = require('http')
  , util = require('util')

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/upload' && req.method === 'POST') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

The author (Andrew Kelley) [recommends](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html) avoiding bodyParser, so you're right to avoid it, but multiparty seems to solve a similar issue for me.

Comment: is there a way to use this as a middleware? I dont want to include this everywhere

Comment: @nilveryboring I'm not sure what you mean... You could definitely put this somewhere that could be reused... I don't know why you'd need this everywhere....

Comment: Ok.. I have tried this our as well. How do I get the file without setting the response header?? I want to do other process then if ok.. set the response header or set error back. res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files})); ..I just want the file sent but leaving the header alone???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `connect-multiparty` (https://github.com/andrewrk/connect-multiparty)

It can be used as middleware in the routes you want to accept uploads.

Comment: In connect-multiparty README, it says to use multiparty instead so this doesn't seem to be a valid alternative to the above question