# Express 3.4.8 Photo uploading issue - how to solve without using bodyParser()?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, mongoose, middleware

**my code at Gist:** https://gist.github.com/yhagio/10654836

I'm new to Express, tried from the example of the book "Node.js in Action - Chapter.9"(Uploading photo).
The author uses Express version "3.4.0" but I used "3.4.8" and I ran into this issue,

The Error message when I try to upload images:

`500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined`

**routes/photos.js**

```
...
exports.submit = function (dir) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    var img = req.files.photo.image; // ---- This 'photo' part is undefined
    var name = req.body.photo.name || img.name;
    var path = join(dir, img.name);

    fs.rename(img.path, path, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); };

      Photo.create({
          name:name,
          path:req.name
        }, function (err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); };
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  };
};
```

but I found that in my app.js (bodyParser() is no longer used since 3.4.8)

**app.js**(In my code Express 3.4.8)

```
...
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());       // Instead of bodyParser()
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // Instead of bodyParser()
...
```

But in author's code has bodyParser().

**app.js**(Author uses Express 3.4.0

```
...
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // This is no longer used in latest version
```

So, I was wondering if I can fix this issue by using multer (http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/replacement-for-bodyparser-connect-multipart/):

```
app.use(express.json());       
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(multer({ dest: './public/photos' })); // I tried this
```

This didn't solve. Please help me. Thank you.

**UPDATE: Solution I figured out**

This code worked(routes/photos.js)

```
exports.submit = function (dir) {
  return function(req, res, next){
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
      var img = files.image[0];
      var name = fields.name || img.originalFilename;
      var path = join(dir, img.originalFilename);
      fs.rename(img.path, path, function(err){
        if(err){return next(err); };
        Photo.create({
          name: name,
          path: img.originalFilename
        }, function(err){
          if(err){return next(err); };
          res.redirect('/');
        });
      });
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: You've named the file input `photo[name]` and you're looking for `req.body.photo`, also `req.files` should contain the uploaded files, and why would it be an object with a `photo` property? There's seems to be quite a bit of discrepancies here ?

Comment: `req.body.photo.name || img.name` Default to original
file name if isn't named on uploading from the form. And `req.files` gets the uploading file(image), so I think it seems ok here but I'm not sure if this part causes the issue :(

Comment: You should post this in the Manning forum for the book http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=790

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you given [node-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty) a try? Here's example usage from the README:

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty')
  , http = require('http')
  , util = require('util')

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/upload' && req.method === 'POST') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

The author (Andrew Kelley) [recommends](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html) avoiding bodyParser, so you're right to avoid it, but multiparty seems to solve a similar issue for me.

Comment: Thank @kentcdodds, I managed to figure out using multiparty :) solution updated!

Comment: @Yuichi awesome! Make sure to accept the answer for future Google searchers to find it more easily.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Instead, it offers an alternative solution. See my answer for a direct response to the initial query.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it no longer works is because the [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) library is no longer included in Express. If you want to continue using formidable, follow these instructions.

The proper way to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) with Express 4.x is:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

To access the files:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

exports.submit = function (dir) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            // The files object here is what you expected from req.files
        });
    });
});
```

Note: if you're trying to use multiple, set:

```
form.multiples = true;
```