# AJAX multipart form to Node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I had a working AJAX form which was automatically generated using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/. After updating to Express.js 4, the data received is empty. req.body returns {} instead of form data. How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multipart/form-data upload - Nodejs - expressjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027737/multipart-form-data-upload-nodejs-expressjs)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a multipart middleware: formidable or busboy.